# Distinct Help

Tags: mysql

Alright so I have a table, in this table are two columns with ID's. I want to make one of the columns distinct, and once it is distinct to select all of those from the second column of a certain ID.

Originally I tried:

```
select distinct inp_kll_id from kb3_inv_plt where inp_plt_id = 581;
```

However this does the where clause first, and then returns distinct values.

Alternatively:

```
select * from (select distinct(inp_kll_id) from kb3_inv_plt) as inp_kll_id where inp_plt_id = 581;
```

However this cannot find the column `inp_plt_id` because distinct only returns the column, not the whole table.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Each kll_id may have one or more plt_id. I would like unique kll_id's for a certain kb3_inv_plt id.

```
| inp_kll_id | inp_plt_id |
|       1941 |      41383 |
|       1942 |      41276 |
|       1942 |      38005 |
|       1942 |      39052 |
|       1942 |      40611 |
|       1943 |       5868 |
|       1943 |       4914 |
|       1943 |      39511 |
|       1944 |      39511 |
|       1944 |      41276 |
|       1944 |      40593 |
|       1944 |      26555 |
```

Comment: please give some example table and expected output; looks almost like by "make distinct" you mean "pick values of the first id that only happen once" (which isn't the SQL semantics), but this is attempted mind-reading on my part, a small example would help!

Comment: I still don't get it... what you originally tried should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do mean, by "make distinct", "pick only `inp_kll_id`s that happen just once" (not the SQL semantics for `Distinct`), this should work:

```
select inp_kll_id
 from kb3_inv_plt
 group by inp_kll_id
 having count(*)=1 and inp_plt_id = 581;
```

Comment: This makes sense except that the plt_id column 'gets removed' for output. 

Changing it to
`select *
 from kb3_inv_plt
 group by inp_kll_id
 having count(*)=1 and inp_plt_id = 581;`
Worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get all the distinct first (alias 'a' in my following example) and then join it back to the table with the specified criteria (alias 'b' in my following example).

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (
            SELECT 
            DISTINCT    inp_kll_id 
            FROM        kb3_inv_plt 
            ) a
LEFT JOIN   kb3_inv_plt b
        ON  a.inp_kll_id = b.inp_kll_id
WHERE       b.inp_plt_id = 581
```

Answer (score 0):

> in this table are two columns with
>   ID's. I want to make one of the
>   columns distinct, and once it is
>   distinct to select all of those from
>   the second column of a certain ID.

```
SELECT distinct tableX.ID2
FROM tableX
WHERE tableX.ID1 = 581
```

I think your understanding of distinct may be different from how it works.  This will indeed apply the where clause first, and then get a distinct list of unique entries of tableX.ID2, which is exactly what you ask for in the first part of your question.

By making a row distinct, you're ensuring no other rows are exactly the same. You aren't making a column distinct.  Let's say your table has this data:

```
ID1   ID2
10    4
10    3
10    7
4     6
```

When you select distinct ID1,ID2 - you get the same as select * because the rows are already distinct.

Can you add information to clear up what you are trying to do?